# Assign default arguments to Python class members

Tags: python, arguments

I am trying to instantiate a class from a dict. In the class constructor, I assign default values to some class members if not given:

```
class Country(object):
    def __init__(self, continent, country = "Zimbabwe"):
        # do stuff
```

The dict I am instantiating from has keys with same name as my class members. I instantiate from the dict like so:

```
country = Country(
    continent = dictionary["continent"],
    country   = default_value if "country" not in dictionary else    dictionary["country"]
)
```

As can be seen, it is possible that the dictionary might not have a key corresponding to the class name. In this case, if the key, "country" doesn't exist, I would like to leave the class member country at its default value, i.e. "Zimbabwe". Is there an elegant way to do this? Something in the manner of:

```
country = dictionary["country"] if "country" in dictionary else pass
```

This is however not possible. I know I can have a dictionary of default values as a static member of the Country class and do it like so:

```
country = Country.default_values["country"] if "country" not in dictionary else dictionary["country"]
```

But it seems like an overkill. Any better way?

Comment: You don't need to use backslashes inside parentheses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `**mapping` calling syntax to apply a dictionary as keyword arguments:

```
Country('Africa', **dictionary)
```

If the dictionary has a `country` key, it'll be passed to the `__init__` method as a keyword argument. If it does not, then `country` is set to the default specified in the method signature.

Demo:

```
>>> class Country(object):
...     def __init__(self, continent='Europe', country='Great Britain'):
...         print 'Continent: {}, Country: {}'.format(continent, country)
... 
>>> dictionary = {'continent': 'Africa', 'country': 'Zimbabwe'}
>>> Country(**dictionary)
Continent: Africa, Country: Zimbabwe
<__main__.Country object at 0x100582550>
>>> Country(**{'country': 'France'})
Continent: Europe, Country: France
<__main__.Country object at 0x100582510>
```

There is a mirror syntax to this for function signatures; `**mapping` in the argument list *captures* keyword arguments not explicitly named:

```
def __init__(self, continent='Europe', country='Great Britain', **kw):
```

Any additional keyword arguments beyond `continent` and `country` end up in the dictionary `kw` that way. You can use it to support arbitrary arguments, or to ignore additional keyword arguments passed in without exceptions being thrown.

Comment: And don't forget to use `**kwargs` in the arguments' list if the `dictionary` could contain keys not used in `__init__`